# Self join/update of table with data in same table

Tags: sql-server-2005, self-join

Due to combining old and new system data in a table I have a list of data like this:

```
Work no    Work name
=========  =========
123456     James
123456     James, (123456)
```

And I want to update to:

```
Work_no    Work_name
=========  =========
123456     James
123456     James
```

I tried building an update statement, wasn't too confident in it so ran it as an equivalent select statement to see what returned and it seems to be running in an infinite loop (there's about 200k records and when I stopped it it was at somewhere in 2 Million returned!) although what it was returning at the start looked fine it just seemed to be duplicating or something:

```
UPDATE c1
set c1.Work_name = c.Work_name
FROM table c1
INNER JOIN table c ON c1.Work_no = c.Work_no 
where charindex(',',c1.Work_name) > 0
```

Only got experience doing the simplest update statements - a bit stuck with this one if anyone could suggest what I am doing wrong and best way to rectify it?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: can you please provide some sample data from where you are getting records to update the data  ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index built on work_no?
Did you try:

```
UPDATE #table set Work_name = (select top 1 c.Work_name FROM #table c where #table.Work_no = c.Work_no and charindex(',',c.Work_name) = 0) where charindex(',',c.Work_name) > 0
```